# Can "fold" be used as a noun to describe groups in k-fold cross-validation?

Tags: cross-validation, terminology

In a *k*-fold cross-validation, we divide the data into *k* groups. Are these groups called the "folds"? Can the word "fold" be used when I talk about these groups? Is it usual? Is the "fold" even a noun in this context in the statistical English?

If not, how do you call these *k* groups? Just "groups"?

PS: I am not a native speaker so I cannot judge it by "feeling"... I haven't found any dictionary definition of the noun "fold" that would be fitting. Anyway, I do not feel like asking this question other people than statisticians, since the English language used in statistics might be very different from the common English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use *fold* as a noun when referring to the groups:

> An alternative to LOOCV is k-fold CV. This approach involves randomly k-fold CV dividing the set of observations into k groups, or *folds*, of approximately equal size. The first fold is treated as a validation set...

Source: Chapter 5.1.3 in *Introduction to Statistical Learning* by James, Witten, Hastie and Tibshirani.

Comment: Thank you!! Looks like the main author, [Gareth James](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gareth_M._James), is a native speaker as he is from New Zealand, and the other authors are native speakers too :-))

Comment: You are totally right. Another proof :-)) *blockCV: An r package for generating spatially or environmentally separated folds for k-fold cross-validation of species distribution* models https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.13107

Comment: I am not a native speaker, but I am using the word myself and I have heard it multiple times from many statisticians. When teaching, I use both "folds" and "groups" and I would not say that I prefer one to another. ISLR is just an example that I had at hand, but I definitely encountered "fold" in other textooks. So yes, I would say it is a common term.

Comment: Thanks @Misius! You are using the word "fold" in which context? Cross-validation?

Comment: @Tomas Yes, exactly in the context you described.